# type expression must be an array type but it resolved to string

Tags: java, arrays, string, 2d

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {
static void displayPathtoPrincess(int n, String [] grid){
    char p;
    if(grid[0][0]=='p')
    {
            for(int i=0;i<(n-1)/2;i++)
            {
                System.out.println("UP\nLEFT\n");
            }
    }
    else if(grid[0][n-1]=='p')
    {
        for(int i=0;i<(n-1)/2;i++)
        {
                System.out.println("UP\nRIGHT\n");
        }
    }
    else if(grid[n-1][0]=='p')
    {
        for(int i=0;i<(n-1)/2;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("DOWN\nLEFT\n");
        }
    }
    else if(grid[n-1][n-1]=='p')
    {
        for(int i=0;i<(n-1)/2;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("DOWN\nRIGHT");
        }
    }
  }
public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int m;
        m = in.nextInt();
        int grid[] = new int[m];
        for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            grid[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

    displayPathtoPrincess(m,grid);
    }
}
```

Hey, i passed the several conditions like "grid[0][0]=='p'" in the if statement as you can see in the code, where grid is a 2d array and p is a character, but i am getting the error "the type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to string". I have been trying to figure this out for a while now but i haven't found any solution.
note: i am new to java and i am trying to improve myself. Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What's the type of `'p'`?

Comment: What's the type of `grid`?

Comment: Your code does not even compile. First: in main() 'grid' is declared as an array of int. But formal parameter of your sub method takes a array of String. Second: Within your sub method you reference the array of String as it would be a two dimensonal array of Character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of parameter grid is One dimensional String array. But you are accessing it as if it were a two dimensional char array. You should change the implementation by comparing `String.charAt(position)`.